# Has Mukesh Solanski's OTP Pinview shutdown?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, github

I seems cannot import his github dependencies despite using the right address:

```
implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.1.2'
```

When I build, Android Studio cannot find it.

Is there any other alternative? I found chaos pinview but I wanna try his as well.

Comment: if android studio says it cant find it then it's probably gone, asking for alternatives here is off-topic unfortunately. we're not support for this library, so you should actually be asking on the github itself

Comment: Like other than his dependencies, is there anyone else's that can be used? Chaos' OTP seems doesnt look very appealing

Comment: `asking for alternatives here is off-topic unfortunately.`

Comment: I can still see it here https://jitpack.io/#mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview/2.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview/2.1.0) says you can find up to 2.1.0 in the Mulesoft repository. So you need to configure another maven repository in the top-level build.gradle and downgrade the dependency version. Or find another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the library but for that you need to do the following

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

add the above line in settings.gradle like this:

```
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  
    
    //add jitpack here
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    
}
}
rootProject.name = "Example"
include ':app'
```